# Convert immutable object to plain object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I am working with reactjs and don't know why I am getting data like

```
Map {size: 5, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
```

Why I am getting this type of data on simple form submit?... How do I change this in simple object?... And I know it can be changed using `.toJSON()` but actually I don't want this type...

**My react component**

```
class AdminUsersForm extends PureComponent {
  submitForm = data => {
    console.log(data, 'dfsgggggggggggggg')
  }
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submitForm)}> 
        <label>firstName</label>
        <Field
          name="firstName"
          className="textInput"
          component={InputField}
        />
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is an immutable object created using immutable js [Here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

You can manipulate and do a lot of things with your object. Example. To get item by key just use.

```
myImmutableObj.get('MyObjKey');
```

See the documentation [Here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Also you can create a similar obj like below.

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable');

let myObject = fromJS({
   name: 'My name',
   lastName: 'My Surname'
});

// This will print similar object from your pic.
console.log(myObject);


// here will print name value which is 'My name'
console.log(myObject.get('name');
```

Comment: thank you Nuru... I got your point... but why I am getting immutable data because I have created simple redux form nothing else... Am I missing something?